# Spring Boot - Erro 404 sem sentido

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http-status-404

Estou iniciando com Spring boot e criei um projeto pelo [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) com `Spring Boot 2.0.5` e as dependencias `Web, PostgreSQL e DevTools`, importei o projeto no IntelliJ, até ai tudo certo, ai fui seguindo uns tutoriais que vi na internet e criei um package no mesmo lugar aonde esta a class com o `@SpringBootApplication` chamado de `controller` e dentro eu criei uma classe `TesteController`, com o seguinte codigo:

```
package com.projetospringboot.meuprojeto.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
        System.out.println("entrou");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

e depois na pasta `templates` eu criei um arquivo html chamado `index.html` e executei o projeto, de acordo com os tutoriais que eu vi e com a lógica se eu abrisse o navegador e acessasse `localhost:8080/home` ele deveria me mostrar o html que eu fiz porém ele retorna um erro dizendo:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this 
as a fallback.

Mon Sep 17 17:37:48 BRT 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

e o que eu entendi desse erro é que ele nn tem uma rota mapeada para `/error` e isso eu vejo como resolver depois pq o que ele quer dizer é que deu um erro 404 e que como nn tem uma rota pra `/error` ele mostrou isso, a questão é, porque ele ta dando erro 404?
Ja tentei trocar o `return` do método `index()` pra todo tipo de rota `"./index", "../index", "templates/index", "./templates/index", "index.html", "./index.html"` e etc.. mas nenhum funcionou.

ta aqui um print da hierarquia das pastas do projeto:
[image: Hierarquia das pastas do Projeto]

o código da classe com o metodo main:

```
package com.projetospringboot.meuprojeto;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.projetospringboot.meuprojeto.controller"})
public class MeuProjetoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MeuProjetoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para chamar o index, você precisa colocar o @RequestMapping("/").

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String index() {
    System.out.println("entrou");
    return "index";
}
```

Sua URL vai ficar assim: localhost:8080/<nome_app_no_pom>
Sua hierarquia está correta e a classe de inicialização @SpringBootApplication (se não for gerar .war) também.

Answer (score 0):

Coloque a classe principal da aplicação acima dos outros pacotes. Mude para a perspectiva packages no Intellij e cheque se a classe que contem a anotação`@SpringBootApplication`está na raiz.

Comment: Sobre a classe principal, a classe com o `@SpringBootApplication`, estar acima das outras, int, esse não é o meu problema pq eu fiz um teste naquele metodo `index()` eu coloquei um `System.out.println("entrou")` só pra testar se o metodo esta sendo executado e ele estava sendo executado sim, e tbm eu tentei mover o arquivo `index.html` para o meu pacote controller, ou seja, abaixo da classe q contém o `@SpringBootApplication` e mesmo assim deu o mesmo erro, o que sera q pode ser?

Comment: Adicione a anotação  `@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = IndexController.class)` na classe principal.

Comment: Também não funcionou :(

Answer (score -3):

Adicione o thymeleaf no pom.xml:
[Thymeleaf dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clMQz.png)